# Powershell - Search Exchange mailbox and emails

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm not really sure if this is possible with Powershell so thought I would ask here first for a quick brainstorm! Essentially I need to search through all mailboxes in a given Exchange looking for specific strings - multiple forms of these strings - lets say in this case - any email containing a set of 6 numbers in any of the following formats:

```
`xx-xx-xx
 xxxxxx
 xxx-xxx`
```

Where x is a number in this case. So if any of these strings are found in the mail, it logs to a text file the mailbox and email/subject it is contained in.

My logic would be as follows:

```
Search Exchange and loop for every mailbox
Recurse in every mailbox looking for matches for the above criteria
If it finds something - get info about that mail, write to text file
Continue loop
```

Any ideas!

Thanks

Comment: For 2007 or 2010 versions to be honest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is for Exchange 2010 from the Exchange Management Shell:

```
#Assign the role to the required user account
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role “Mailbox Import Export” -User administrator
#Restart the shell

#This would search every mailbox for messages containing the word xx-xx-xx in the message body,
#and export them to the administrator mailbox in a subfolder called Export
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery “Body:’*xx-xx-xx*’” -TargetMailbox administrator -TargetFolder Export
```

You need to do this for any `[string]` you are searching.
I think there's cmdlet also in exchange 2007 to do same thing, but I can swear.

Comment: Thanks - the problem is the xx-xx-xx could be any numbers - how can I search it for any number sequence, not a specific one? ie. "Body:'xx-xx-xx-xx' where X is any integer?

Comment: @TheD. Oops.. You're rigth... but unfortunately -searchquery doesn't support regex. I try to search some other solution but It's an hard thing...

Comment: @TheD Find nothing with Exchange module for powershell. You can try searching for a 3th party tools.